# Apache Vhosts - subdomaining

Tags: apache2, vhost

I am a little new to the apache vhosts configuration and for educational purposes I wish to set up a domain and a subdomain.

The domain is already set up under the name `example.com`. Now I want to create a subdomain `test.example.com`.

Consider the following (desired) directory structure:

```
- site_com
   - test
       - index.html
   - css
       - gobal.css
   - index.html
```

I have managed to do this by doing:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName test.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot site_com/test

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory site_com/test>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

I successfully go to the correct index.html when I go to `test.example.com`.

Now consider that index.html is a very simple page that contains a relative path to load a css file from the `site_com/css` directory. by using the following code in `test/index.html`:

```
<link href="../css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

However the CSS does not load. The reason is a 404 response. I have verified that the actual directory structure is correct and I have no idea why this behaves like that. I have used webhosts before and there a subdomain is also just a folder in your top domain but everything works perfectly. The stack software I use is called ZPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to load `http://example.com/css/global.css` as its for a different domain - the browser doesn't know about the directory structure on your server and cannot link the 2 sites together without a direct URL

Comment: Is there not some way to tell apache that the parent directory (would be root domain) files are available aswell?

Comment: You could set up a symlink site_com/test/css that points to site_com/css and have Apache follow symlinks, but it can't serve files outside of its root directory otherwise.

Comment: If you did that, you would load /css/global.css rather than ../css/global.css